# ¿Como modificar archivos en Java?

Tags: java, archivo, filewriter

Tengo un problema, tengo un archivo txt en java donde tengo la siguiente información:

Pais,Ciudad,Fecha,Casos

Mexico,Guadalajara,10/12/2020,5

España,Madrid,12/03/ 2020,6

Londres,Manchester,/14/02/2020,10

Italia,Roma,9/01/2020,

lo que quiero hacer es sumar los números que se encuentran en la columna de casos lo estoy haciendo mediante de un BufferedReader donde recorre la columna de casos y va sumando los números el problema es que donde no encuentra un numero si no un espacio vació me arroja un error ejemplo lee el 5 después le el siguiente renglón y encuentra un 6 lo suma después suma 10 después se va al siguiente renglón y no hay numero entonces ocurre el error lo que se me ocurre hacer es en los renglones donde no hay numero poner un 0 pero no se como hacerlo?

Dejo el código donde los sumo:

```
public String [] cargarDatos() {/* Crear el registro y regresarlo*/
        String [] temp = {};

        try {
            if(fr != null){
                temp = br.readLine().split(",");
                total_c += Integer.parseInt(temp[3]);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacer una prueba despues del split().  Puede probar cuanto cosas hay en temp

```
if(temp.count >= 3) { 
total_c += ... etc
}
```

o probar si temp[3] es null.

```
if (temp[3] != null) {
total_c += ... etc
}
```

Comment: Si también estaba pensado en probar si temp[3] != null  entonces hacer la suma ¿pero cuando no lo sea que debe hacer ? porque si lo dejo como me lo mencionas sigue dando error.

Comment: Lo que debe hacer depiende en lo que necesita.  Puede ignorar la linea y regresar del metodo.  Puede asumar que null significa 0.  Puede asumar que null significa 3.141592.  Puede echar un excepion.  Es para usted para determinar.

Comment: Entiendo que null significa 0 pero a lo que me refiero es como ignorar esa linea vacía, que hago para que no la tome en cuenta y siga con las lineas que están abajo de la linea vacía para que siga sumando

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta.  Su metodo no "sigue sumando".  Suma o no, depiende en si temp[3] tiene sentido.  Tambien no entiendo el porque regresa temp[], (no sabemos como llama cargarDatos() ) pero es una pregunta diferente.